# Einstein notation

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, manifolds, tensors

I'm confused about a specific issue that I have with the Einstein notation (for tensor fields on manifolds).

I want to write the following thing:

> Let $X$ be a smooth manifold. Choosing local coordinates $(q^1, \dots, q^n)$
>    on $X$ defines natural coordinates $(q^1, \dots,  q^n, p^1, \dots, p^n)$ on $T^{*}X$:  the point with coordinates $(q^1, \dots,
> q^n, p^1, \dots, p^n)$ is the covector $p^i dq^i \in T^{*}X$.

As you see, there is a problem with $p^i dq^i$: both indices are up. A such covector should be written $p_i \, dq^i$. On the other hand, coordinate functions are written with upper indices, so as coordinate functions on $T^{*}X$ it seems like $(q^1, \dots,
q^n, p^1, \dots, p^n)$is correct.

What is going on? What should I write?

Comment: $p^i$ are coordinates on the cotangent space part of $T^*M$, so if you want to use sum convention it would be better to have the index in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: [don't use Einstein notation here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1926173/1543).

The form of the tautological one form $\sum_i p_i ~\mathrm{d}q^i$ (Incidentally, I do think that the canonical coordinates for $T^*M$ should have the momentum variables with lowered indices) is dependent on the coordinate used on $T^*M$; while you can require that canonical coordinates be used, the computation still only makes sense in those type of coordinates, and so it is best to avoid confusion by not using Einstein convention at all.