# How to justify Einstein notation manipulations without explicitly writing sums?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, notation

In calculating the expression for the coordinates of the Lie Bracket of two vector fields, one has to "interchange the roles of the dummy indices $i$ and $j$ in the second term" (p.187, Lee *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*) i.e. justify the following equality: $$X^j \frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x\ ^j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} - Y^i \frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x\ ^j} \overset{?}{=} X^j \frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x\ ^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} - Y^j\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x\ ^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}. $$ Now writing out the sums explicitly this is fairly easy to do: $$\sum_i\sum_j \left[X^j \frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x\ ^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} - Y^i \frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} \right] = \sum_i\sum_j\left[X^j \frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x\ ^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \right] - \sum_i\sum_j\left[ Y^i \frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} \right] \\ = \sum_i\sum_j\left[X^j \frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x\ ^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \right] - \sum_j\sum_i \left[ Y^j \frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \right] = \sum_i\sum_j\left[X^j \frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x\ ^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \right] - \sum_i\sum_j \left[ Y^j \frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \right] \\ = \sum_i\sum_j \left[X^j \frac{\partial Y^i}{\partial x\ ^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} - Y^j \frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \right] .$$ However, writing out all of these sums is fairly laborous and defeats the purpose of using Einstein notation in the first place.

> **Question:** Is there a list somewhere of allowed manipulations using Einstein notation? I would like to use such a list to rigorously justify manipulations like the above using Einstein notation in the future with a clean conscience.

I could probably supply the proofs writing out the sums explicitly myself, so the list of allowed manipulations doesn't need to come with proofs for all of the rules.

**Note:** This is related to a [previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999595/does-the-einstein-summation-convention-still-work-for-infinite-sums), where I asked (essentially) whether and if so which and how many manipulations using Einstein notation require finiteness of the index sets in order to be justified. Note that the above calculation is another example where the finiteness of the indexing sets is appealed to implicitly in order to justify switching the order of summation in the second-to-last step (the third-to-last step consists simply of renaming variables).

Comment: Is there a typo? In your first equation the first expressions on both sides are equal. If it is not a type then you only need to show that the second expressions are the same.

Comment: @MrYouMath Yes you are correct on both accounts -- I just included the first terms for completeness, and since otherwise the context would be unclear, as well as why the manipulation would not be obviously true. Mainly without including the first terms, the first and last steps of the computation using the sums would not be necessary. I agree it is difficult to read because $i$ and $j$ look too similar.

Answer (score 6):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking but let me point out that the calculation you wrote down is correct *even if you erase all the* $\Sigma$s, so you could have written a much shorter calculation to justify this. What is in the background is essentially the distributivity law for the real numbers as well as associativity of multiplication.  Of course you can exploit commutativity of multiplication also but this does not seem to be used in the particular calculation you presented.

To convince yourself that $u^i_j v_i^j + w^j_i x^i_j = u^i_j v_i^j + w^i_j x_i^j$ is a legitimate procedure, first change the names of the variables in the second summand:
$$
u^i_j v_i^j + w^j_i x^i_j = u^i_j v_i^j + w^p_q x_p^q.
$$
Now since both $p$ and $q$ are dummy variables, they can be changed respectively to $i$ and $j$ (in that order), so that we get
$$
u^i_j v_i^j + w^j_i x^i_j = u^i_j v_i^j + w^p_q x_p^q=u^i_j v_i^j + w^i_j x_i^j.
$$
When one uses the Einstein summation convention, the $\Sigma$ signs *carry no additional information at all*; in particular it cannot be said that something can be shown with the $\Sigma$s but not without them.

Comment: That's the definition of the Einstein summation convention!  Whenever the same index is repeated in a subscript and superscript position, there is an implied summation.  If one is not supposed to sum over such a repeated index, a common notational convention is to underline both indices.

Comment: Changing the name of an index is OK because it is merely a dummy variable; its actual name plays no role. Multiplying and adding terms, as I mentioned in my *answer*, is justified by distributivity.

Comment: That's correct, but so long as you are dealing with finite sums you can certainly change the order of summation.  So I still don't see what is bothering you about this calculation.

Comment: That finite sums commute follows from induction on the commutativity of addition, which is a little not straightforward, but that isn't quite what is bothering me. It isn't even this specific calculation in general -- I was able to do the rearrangements using sums in my head and just wrote them down to double check.

Comment: The above calculation is just an example of the phenomenon I am talking about, which perhaps could be described as "renaming indices to values already being used". Reading your new edit what my concerns come down to is the step $u_j^i v_j^i + w_q^px_p^q \to u_j^iv_i^j + w_j^ix_i^j$. In some sense the indices $i,j$ aren't entirely dummy, because seemingly whether or not all terms use the same summing indices determines whether or not they occur in the same summation or different sums -- although the difference is moot because of commutativity and distributivity.

Comment: A better example would be $X^j \tilde{Y}^k$, where we can say that $X^j = \frac{\partial \tilde{x}^k}{\partial x^j} \tilde{X}^k$, where the $k$'s "don't interact" because they are in two separate equations. But then if one wants to insert the change of coordinates, the two expressions $$\frac{\partial \tilde{x}^k}{\partial x^j} \tilde{X}^k \tilde{Y}^k  $$ and $$\frac{\partial \tilde{x}^{\ell}}{\partial x^j} \tilde{X}^{\ell} \tilde{Y}^k $$ aren't the same (I think). So it is somewhat of a question of when one can and can't rename indices, as an even simpler example $a^j b_j \not= a^i b_j$.

Comment: When you have the same index in a superscript notation, the expression is probably meaningless and should be avoided.  It certainly does not make sense at the level of tensors.  The reason the expressions $a^jb_j$ and $a^ib_j$ are not equal is because the first has a repeated index and is therefore a sum, while the second does not have a repeated index and is not a sum.

Answer (score 5):

The same rule you used to transform $i \leftrightarrow j$ in the second line of the second equation also applies in Einstein's notation

$$
u^i v_i = u^jv_j
$$

which is to say that you can call dummy indices the way you like but making sure that only one upper-index sums with only one lower-index. For instance, you can make this

$$
x^i A_{ij} y^j = x^j A_{ji} y^i
$$

but you **cannot** do this

$$
x^i A_{ij} y^j = x^i A_{ii} y^i
$$

Comment: My question comes down more to -- how can one argue elegantly that $u^i_j v_i^j + w^j_i x^i_j = u^i_j v_i^j + w^i_j x_i^j$? Like obviously it is clear when one is renaming all indices in the same way, but here only some of the indices (the indices for $w$ and $x$, but _not_ the indices for $u$ and $v$) are being renamed. I can show it when writing out all of the sums, it involves an explicit appeal to the fact that finite summations commute, but it is hard to appeal to the finite summations commuting without writing out the sums.

Comment: @William In your example the terms $u^i_j v^j_i$ and $w^j_i x^i_j$ do not share any indices, you can then apply the arguement of the dummy indices to each term without affecting the other, in particular you can leave one of them unchanged and change the other

Comment: "You can then apply the argument of the dummy indices to each term without affecting the other" I recognize that this is true, however, how can I show that this is true without writing out all of the summations? I know how to show it is true with using the summations (see above) but it is not clear to me how it can be shown to be true without writing out the summations.

Comment: Hi William. So if I understand you correctly, your idea is how to use Einstein's notation if you have never used a summation before, is that right? I guess most of my intuition about it comes just from having used sums before. The advantage over the $\sum$ notations definitely comes later when expressions become more complicated

Comment: Well sort of, but my point is that one manipulation using Einstein's notation corresponds to four different steps when writing out the sum explicitly. I imagine there are a lot of possible steps involving renaming dummy variables that correspond to multiple steps when written out explicitly. I know all of those steps are obvious -- I guess my problem is that I am taking a commutative algebra course at the same time, so I feel like I want to be able to keep track of all of my steps, to ensure that I am only using allowed properties of addition and multiplication.

Comment: Does it help to make it "more obvious" if you first see that $u^i_j v^j_i + w^j_ix^i_j = (u^i_j v^j_i) + (w^j_ix^i_j)$? With  each set of parentheses, $i$ and $j$ are dummy variables so an expression like  $(u^p_q v^q_p) + (w^r_sx^s_r)$ has exactly the same meaning and the same value.